# Python opening a link with a variable

Tags: python-3.x, telegram

I have a problem with my code created in python.
I would like the URL API telegram to open with a change so that the downloaded item from the site is sent to chat.

```
# Import libraries
import requests
import urllib.request
import time
import sys 
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
stdoutOrigin=sys.stdout 
sys.stdout = open("log.txt", "w")
# Set the URL you want to webscrape from
url = 'https://31asdasdasdasdasd.com/'
# Connect to the URL
response = requests.get(url)
# Parse HTML and save to BeautifulSoup object
soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text, "html.parser")
zapisane = ''
row = soup.find('strong')
print(">> Ilosc opinii ktora przeszla:")
send =  print(row.get_text()) # Print row as text
import urllib.request
u = urllib.request.urlopen("https://api.telegram.org/botid:ts/sendMessage?chat_id=-3channel1&text=")
```

Answer (score 0):

You likely want to use a string format with a variable in your last line of code shown here. Here's a helpful resource for string formatting: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/python-format-function/